# JSP Spring controller HOW to insert button into forEach loop in jsp

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I have something like this. but it doesn't work

```
<div
    style="padding: 10px; border-radius: 10px; font-size: 12px; text-align: center;">
    <c:forEach var="item" items="${university.facultyList}">
        <button value="${item.id}">${item.fullName}</button>
    </c:forEach>
</div>
```

Comment: try to read excetion message

Comment: This code seems valid you probably have an exception in logs. You can print ${university} and ${university.facultyList} before the loops to see these objects are actually in the model.

Comment: thanks. i found the decision. there was the problem in my controller